# Flagged wrong answer - FAQ too unspecific?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

This is the problem at hand:

[Is this a valid float comparison that accounts for a set number of decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180385/is-this-a-valid-float-comparison-that-accounts-for-a-set-number-of-decimal-place)

--Explanation why the answer is wrong skipped--

So I asked myself what can I do if people are unlikely to see that the answer is wrong (My answer at the bottom, my warning buried in the comments) ?

Reading the fine FAQ...

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#flagging
What if I see bad things happening ?

Ok, that seems to be a "bad thing"...
Flag...
Fill out form...

Response:
declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

--Skipped section questioning if wrong answers should be flagged---

If the question/answer should not be flagged at all, then I seriously advise to edit the FAQ. While people are prone to disregard the documentation, I *did* read it and found no clue whatsoever that I should not flag it. Neither you or me want to waste your time for false alarms.

EDIT:
To be clear: Should wrong answers (or technical inaccuracies or whatever) *never* be flagged? Yes or no?
If yes, we can end the post right here.

EDIT 2:
In the comment under the accepted answer it is said that while the FAQ is open to interpretation, the flag interface is not so much open.

I look now at the flag interface.

There is a point: "It needs moderator attention"->"other".

I do not see that it quite clearly states that flagging wrong answers is "not so much open for interpretation".

Is it a good idea that instead

- stating clearly in the FAQ what questions should be flagged
- a moderator gets a false flag, needs to read and understand the question and the answer, denies the flag, the irritated flagger opens a question here, gets flak from the other members, starts a discussion etc. etc.?

Seriously?

Comment: The FAQ isn't there to describe each flag in detail.

Comment: I see a different problem. It's unclear what the OP wants, so it may or may not be achievable. Anyway, "serious problems" doesn't include "answers I consider wrong" in my interpretation.

Comment: Well, now we have a precise question...If you can answer it with yes, please provide an explanation/links/comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is: **Provide a better answer**.

Flagging is used to highlight spam, rants, or otherwise content that doesn't belong on the site. The diamond moderators who action flags, are not subject matter experts, and therefore cannot determine the factual accuracy of a posts.

For that, we have votes. In the question you posted, the OP accepted the answer, and therefore, **for his case scenario** the code and the answer worked for him. He does not post the full details of how deep he wants to go, just to solve his particular problem, and it was solved. In fact, both answerers highlighted the fact that the solution only works in  case by case basis and is affected by precision, and therefore the OP has been warned of possible problems with both solutions.

In fact, your answer counts as something to be flagged, as not an answer, since it reads like a rant. This is not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A. If you are 100% convinced it's the wrong answer, post the **correct answer**. Simple.

Comment: After clearing that up: What about adding that to the Stack Overflow FAQ ? It is even a one-liner, so why not changing it instead of the "If bad things are happening" ?

Comment: @ThorstenS. The flag interface itself quite clearly gives you a decent example of "bad things" to fall in line with the FAQ. The FAQ is open to interpretation. The FAQ flag interface, not so much. If between the two someone, and it does happen, come to the wrong conclusion, the declined flag reason will ensure it doesn't happen again.